# HTML/CSS issue with height and absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I got a bit of a problem which keeps giving me headaches. The solution might be easy but I seriously can't find it. It would be awesome if you could help me out!

My problem is a bit hard to describe but I'll try my best.

Currently I'm working on a new layout for my website and I'm having a problem with height and absolute positioning of content (problem is CSS). Everything looks fine as long as the content of the section isn't higher than the screen height. As soon as this isn't the case anymore the content will overlap any other content on the page and it will be totally messed up.

Here is the HTML:

```
<section id="section1" class="section">
<div class="container">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Text</p>
  <div>
    Other content
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.section {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 32px 0;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  z-index: 5;
}
.section .container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
     -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
       -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

Life demo of the problem can be found here: [Current Progress](http://aeon-sake.com/new-layout/)

Thanks in advance!

Aeon

Comment: Your page doesn't look that bad to me. Apart from the top image and the welcome container beneath it, everything fits between the top and bottom bar. What browser are you using? Can you make a screenshot where your layout fails?

Comment: It fails when screen-width gets too low as on mobile (or simply resize your window).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution for my problem so I decided to make the absolute positioning screen-width-depending and only appearing on screens with 1170px and above.
Smaller screens will see the relative format with some changed attributes.

Question can be closed.